# In github, how can I create merge request for 1 commit only

Tags: git

How do i create a merge request form 1 commit only and ignore the previous commit?

`git commit -m`

Comment: When you make merge request is within a branch, not by commits. So if you only want to send 1 commit with X changes, you should create another branch and pull that changes into your branch. **Note**: this information is based fully in my personal experience, it may be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Pulling in changes for a single commit is called a cherry-pick in git. A merge is merging two independent streams of development, typically with common history, into one "merged" stream. This implicitly includes the entire history of the branch.

The way you can get what you are after though, is to create a new branch from the commit *before* the commit you do not want to include. Then cherry-pick the commit you *do* want into your new branch.  Now you have a fresh branch with just the items you want to include, and that is the branch you initiate the merge request with.